# List files from /inst directory for development of R package

Tags: r, list, package

I was wondering if it is possible to list files in a directory when developing an R package. From [this](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html) page, I read that system.file() should be used to refer to files included in a an R-package. However, this does not seem to work for directories. I'm looking for how to list files in a particular directory: "a" within the "inst" directory, then I would use:

```
list.files(system.file("a/", package = [package_name]))
```

or

```
list.files(system.file("a", package = [package_name]))
```

However, this didn't work and returned an empty string. Furthermore, is it possibly bad practice to refer to list a bunch of .sql files for example within a package?

Comment: I think you forgot inst. Try `list.files(system.file("inst","a", package = [package_name]))`. The package argument points to the root folder of the package, not just any random folder.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I checked why, I used devtools::load_all() somewhere. Before this, it worked perfectly without "inst". I'm doubting now which version is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

`system.file(package = 'package_name')` returns the absolute path to the root of the package directory (literaly from the ?system.file). However, devtools overwrites this function and replaces it with the absolute path to the package working directory (the path from where you initiated the load_all() command) if needed.

However, when the package does not exist (e.g. `system.file(package = 'non_existing_package')`), the path returns a relative path.

```
> system.file('a', package = 'existing_package')
"C:/.../package_directory/a"
> system.file('a', package = 'non_existing_package')
"a"
```

Depending on how your working directory is set, this might work under some circumstances.